# QTextEdit Decrease Indentation of "tab" Key

Tags: qt, qtextedit

I'm trying to make a little **C++** text editor using **Qt**. When I press the `"tab"` key on my keyboard in the editor, it indents the line a lot more than necessary. I would like the code to indent by about 3 spaces rather than what looks to be 11 spaces. Is there any way to change the function of the tab key? Thanks.

Comment: If there isn't a way to directly configure TAB behavior, then override `keyPressEvent` and catch and handle TAB as you see fit.

Comment: Clarification needed: do you want to keep TAB key inserting TAB character (ASCII code 9), and just change the tab width? Or do you want to change it so that TAB key inserts spaces?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To change TAB (ASCII character 9) width, you can use `tabStopWidth` property, which exists for both `QTextEdit` and `QPlainTextEdit` ([doc link)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html#tabStopWidth-prop). It takes tab width in pixels. Note that TAB does not have a fixed width, instead it moves forward to next *TAB stop*, which are at pixel intervals determined by this property, starting from left edge.

If you want TAB width to depend on font, you can use [QFontMetrics](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetrics.html) class to get pixel width for some font and character. Example code:

```
    // this object is QTextEdit or QPlainTextEdit or a subclass
    int fontWidth = QFontMetrics(this->currentCharFormat().font()).averageCharWidth();
    this->setTabStopWidth( 3 * fontWidth );
```